# How long you been waiting to spring that on me? Is the sentence correct?

Tags: present-perfect

Is it a wrong sentence of present-perfect？
but I heard a native speaker said it.
Does it lack 'have' before 'you'?

Comment: Yes, it lacks **have**

Comment: It sounds like slang, urban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is incorrect. The correct sentence would be:

> How long **have** you been waiting to spring that on me?